# Парадокс брадобрея на Python with OOP

Tags: python, алгоритм, ооп, логика

Это [известный парадокс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F), вариант парадокса Рассела.
Есть [код на Python](https://gist.github.com/startling/2289437), который реализует парадокс Рассела, приводя к бесконечной рекурсии.
Там используются именно множества. А я бы хотел в учебно-познавательных целях сделать вариант с брадобреем, используя OOP. Что-то вроде этого:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class People:
    instances = set()

    def __init__(self, name, is_self_shaver):
        self.name = name
        if is_self_shaver:
            self.shaver = self
        else:
            self.shaver = None
        People.instances.add(self)

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls):
        return cls.instances


class Barber(People, metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

Начало, думаю, правильное: класс-синглетон Barber наследуется от People.
Через методы и свойства определяем, бреется ли человек сам.
Но мне никак не удается получить парадокс именно как бесконечную рекурсию!
Как бы я не менял/добавлял методы, получается либо отсутствие объекта, либо просто "все хорошо".
Пробовал и отдельную функцию, пробегающую по всем People.
Если кто-то заинтересуется, буду рад любым идеям!

Comment: ООП никогда не предназначался для моделирования логических утверждений. Наверное, если очень исхитрится, то можно написать класс таким образом, что он будет приводить к рекурсии. Но это будет происходить исключительно в том случае, если где-то внутри у вас будет реализован код, подобный коду по вашей ссылке.

Comment: Да, похоже, что так. Я вроде не такой уж новичок в Питоне, но не получается.
Но все же тут не вопрос доказательств логики, это ясно, что не к ООП.
А отношений между объектами наследуемых классов.